# Preventing airbubbles when placing screen protector?

Tags: phone

Whenever I try and place a screen protector on any electrical device, I always get a load of airbubbles, and my device ends up looking like this:

[image: image of a screen with many air bubbles in the protector]

How can I prevent this from happening, or how can I remove any remaining bubbles?

Answer (score 1):

Work from one corner, very carefully and pushing it flat to the screen as soon as there is contact.
It is very hard to get proper positioning that way but you will not get airbubbles.

You can get around the positioning problem if you have a protecting layer on the screen saver, peel it back just for one corner, position the protector and then pull the protector layer back a little more, pushing down the bit now exposed and check that you do not have airbubbles yet.

It might be possible to re-do the protector you have already placed by pulling it off from one corner till only the opposite corner is still attached, and then reapplying the protector, pressing it down while applying.

I would use either a soft cloth or a soft glove to do the pressing down. Although I myself have used my fingers more than once.
As I have used this method several times, I know it works without danger for the phone or tablet.

Comment: I definitely appreciate this discovery. Thanks for opening my eyes. Up till now, I was applying screen protector not carefully commuting in an Uber or giant wheel.

Answer (score 1):

On phones use a debt/credit card to push the protector along. On a tablet use a plastic ruler.

Start at one end(shortest side) and gently use the card/ruler to work the protector along the screen, working out the bubbles as you go.

Another tip is to use a hair dryer beforehand on the screen to remove all the small hairs that are in the vicinity.

Answer (score 1):

How about this (purely theoretical) modification of jeffry copps answer of Feb 18? I believe his idea of using water to "float" the protector onto the screen is sound, but because of the risk of water getting into the joins of the device, we want to use the barest minimum amount of water. I think I would create a mist of water by using an old medication spray bottle (such as a Beconase spray bottle, as used by many hay fever sufferers): put water in the bottle and spray a very fine mist into the air. Practice a few times to ensure the mist is really fine. Then as the mist drifts down, catch it on the upturned sticky surface of the screen protector. This should ensure you are using as little water as possible. I would also put sticky tape over the exposed joins of the device. Lay the dampened screen protector on the screen and squeeze the moisture out. Have a paper tissue around the edges ready to soak up the escaping moisture.  I haven't tried this! It's only theoretical!

Comment: It may be theoretical, but theoretically this sounds like a good idea :)

Comment: It is still water on the screen of a life phone. Most danger is when the water is pressed out from under the protector, where it gets collected and hard to controll.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing from some of the other answers: Spray some isopropyl alcohol on the surface, and wipe it off so that your are starting with a clean surface. Then spray some more isopropyl alcohol on the surface. It doesn't conduct electricity, so it doesn't matter if it gets into the device (you can actually soak a phone in isopropyl alcohol to dry it out, as a more thorough alternative to rice). I know Walgreens sells it in a very convenient spray bottle. Then place the screen protector on the surface, and use a rubber squeegee (or a credit card, or your fingers) to push the air bubbles and alcohol out. Start in the center, and work your way to the sides.

Answer (score -1):

I observed this in sticker shops how the experts fix the stickers on surfaces perfectly neat without any bubbles formed. The secret is they apply some slippery fluid(At home, we could use water and shampoo) on the surface where they going to paste the sticker. The fluid helps in not allowing the adhesive present in the sticker to touch the surface thus enables the user to have the sticker moved freely. Once the sticker is fixed in a place, they use a equipment to press the sticker against the surface and squeeze out the slippery water out, by which the adhesive gets fixed onto the surface.

The same idea could be very well used in fixing thin mobile screen guards.

Comment: Water on a working phone's screen? I would not dare that at home. I would not even use other fluids which are less likely to drip into the equipment.

Comment: I answered in a practical point of view. Assuming that user under life hacks would be skilled enough doing such things.

Comment: This is a technique commonly used to apply automotive window tint, but as @Willeke mentioned I would be concerned about the excess liquid damaging the device. Perhaps being extra cautious to avoid spillage and using a paper towel on the screen edges to absorb the fluid might work.